# Why am I only getting the content of one of my items?

Tags: node.js, express, routes, mongoose

I have a simple comments app which enables the user to enter a comment into the system via a form and these are then logged onto a list on the bottom of the page.

I wanted to modify it so that a user could click a comment once it is created and it would load up the associated content that goes with that comment.

My schema:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var CommentSchema = new Schema({
    title: String,
    content: String,
    created: Date
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Comment', CommentSchema);
```

My app.js routes:

```
app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/create', create);
app.use('/:title', show);
```

My show route:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Comment = mongoose.model('Comment', Comment);

router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    Comment.findOne(function(err, comment){
        console.log(comment.content)
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

I have three comments in my system and saved in my database, each with unique contents, But whenever I click on a comment, no matter what it is. I am only getting the content that is associated with the first comment.

Why is this?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to provide a [`condition` for `.findOne()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOne) to retrieve a specific document:

> **Model.findOne(**conditions, [fields], [options], [callback]**)**

Without one, an empty `condition` is implied that matches every document in the collection:

```
Comment.findOne({}, function ...);
```

And, `.findOne()` simply retrieves the 1st of those that are matched.

---

With the `:title` parameter in the route for `show` and `title` property in the `Schema`, one possible condition would be:

```
Comment.findOne({ title: req.params.title }, function ...);
```

Though, if the `title`s aren't unique in order to find the "*right*" one, you'll have make the `condition` more specific. The [`_id`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/glossary/#term-id) or [`id`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-id) would be the most distinct.

```
app.use('/:id', show);
```

```
Comment.findOne({ id: req.params.id }, function ...);

// or
Comment.findById(req.params.id, function ...);
```

Also adjusting any links and `res.redirect()`s to fill pass the `id` for `:id`.

Comment: Thanks, i've now changed my route to read:

    Comment.findOne({ _id: req.params.id}, function(err, comment){
      console.log(comment.content)
    });

But I'm now getting an error in my terminal saying the 'content' is a property of null.

Comment: @Keva161 A `null` for `comment` means the `condition` didn't match any documents. Check whether an `err` occurred. Also, make sure everything related to the route uses `id` rather than `title` -- `:id` is in the route, any `href`s and `redirect`s pointing to it use the `id` in the path, and that `req.params.id` has a value [that's numeric](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/object-id/).

Comment: If I try to log out req.params.id from my app.js, it provides a value as expected. However, if I try to log it out via my show route, I just get an undefined message.